# Lumen - Call other controller method and get response

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-5, lumen

In order to add the ability of bulk API requests to my api I have added a new method to one my controllers.
The method takes as input an array of objects and calls another method in the same controller (which may throw an exception). 
see the following code:

```
       foreach ($objects as $object) {
            $request = (array)$object;
            $request = Request::create('/someinternalurl', 'POST', $request);
            $response = app()->dispatch($request);
            $responses[] = json_decode($response->getContent());
        }
```

the problem is that for 10 objects for example, this code takes about 15 seconds. 
In addition i have tried to search for other solutions, but all i found seems to result 
 the same respone time or many changes to my API.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use method directly, rather than sending request to corresponding route. 
For example:

```
$response = (new YourController())->yourMethod($object);
```

Comment: you can ask the container to resolve the instance of the controller (will allow for dependency injection if needed), you can have the container also call the method on the controller for you (which will allow for method injection, if needed)